# Calling soap API without WSDL in python

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I need to call a SOAP API which has no WSDL.

The API Server is written in Perl's `SOAP::Lite` and using `SOAP::Lite` as client works without WSDL.
I'm trying `zeep` and `suds` in python but both of them need WSDL.

How can I use SOAP API without WSDL?
Is there any soap library to work without WSDL?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried searching for the WSDL manually?

For example.

The URL you have

```
http://dummy.com/foo
```

The URL you have to look for to get the service's WSDL.

```
http://dummy.com/foo?wsdl
```

I've worked with SOAP in the last few months on Python and I haven't found any library that I could use without the service's WSDL.

Many libraries are now deprecated on Python, you have very limited choices to work with.

Comment: yes; i'm using [Nictool](https://www.nictool.com/docs/api/)'s API which uses perl's SOAP::Lite for server and provides no WSDL!